# Undervolting on Ubuntu

Tags: cpu, intel-cpu

I decided to undervolt my cpu and I saw online there are 2 main programs to do it on Windows: XTU and ThrottleStop.

However it seems there aren't versions of these programs for Ubuntu or for Linux in general.

Do you know any other reliable program for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

There's [undervolt](http://github.com/georgewhewell/undervolt) available. You can install it from PyPi by running the command:

```
pip install undervolt
```

or from source by running the command:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/georgewhewell/undervolt.git
```